# How do I make a WHERE clause where the identifier can be both INT and VARHAR?

Tags: mysql, grafana

In Grafana I have got a variable dropdown where the available options are both ids and names. The "id" field is an INT type and the "name" field is VARCHAR type.

So what I'm trying to achieve is

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=${identifier} OR name='${identifier}'
```

How can I solve this. Having two dropdowns isn't going to be the solution since this will confuse the user because they need to reset one of the dropdowns before the other works.

Comment: `WHERE '${identifier}' IN (id, name)`. The context is string one, so `id` will be converted to string implicitly.

Comment: Liability for [**SQL injection**](https://xkcd.com/327/) if indeed the syntax is `name='...'`.